# Why this query doesn't work with such condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to solve some tasks from this http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial
At the last task(number 8) I wrote a query:

```
select name, continent from world a
where a.population > 
(select 3*max(population) from world b
where b.continent = a.continent)
```

but this query doesn't return any rows. But works almost the same query(just added an additional conditin in the end of subquery). But what's the matter? Why doesn't it return raws even if names of countries are the same?

```
select name, continent from world a
where a.population > 
(select 3*max(population) from world b
where b.continent = a.continent and a.name <> b.name)
```

Comment: You cannot use the table alias `a` in the sub-query.. What is the output that you are trying to get?

Comment: actually he can use columns in parent query in subquery.

Comment: Take a look at what entries are included in the subquery in both cases and note the difference ,-)

Comment: i don't think your first query should return a result. you are trying to get the continent having greater population of 3 times higher populated continent.
you should used group by clause. if you can add the structure of table and some data then we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Let me translate what both query does to english, so you can realize the difference.

**first query;** compare and get all countries who are on the same continent and have more than 3 times of the maximum populated country in that continent.

**second query;** compare and get all countries who are on the same continent and have more than 3 times of the maximum populated country in that continent except himself.

in your first query the maximum populated country cannot be more than 3 times more populated than himself if he is the max populated country himself so your query returns 0 results.

but on the second query the maximum populated country EXCEPT himself can have population 3 times more than other countries in the same continent.

Comment: I know it. But why does it return 0 rows in the case of the first query? It is just not necessary that the same country has the maximum of population. I just can;t understand.

Comment: if you add the same country on the second query, select cannot find a case where there are less populated country in the subquery because the country on the parent query is also in the subquery and if he is the maximum populated country, he can have at most the same population not less

Comment: let me illustrate
population 10 mil first country and maximum in his continent
in subquery max population will be returned as 10 mil and the compare of 10mil>10mil will return false thus 0 results

Comment: population 1 mil seconds country, maximum of his continent is 10 mil son the compare will be 1mil>10mil = false thus 0 results

Comment: In the case, when the same country in the main query and the subquery doesn't have the maximum population of the continent, it won't return 0 rows?

Comment: but if you add the not same country condition, in first example you'll for example have 10mil>3mil which is the second most populated country thus returns result

Comment: the question is actually find the continents whose most populated country has more than 3 times people than the second most populated country.